# how to justify that "Tile Cover" is in NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Hi im learning for a exam in Theoretical computer science. And im learning with the exams of the last years because the task setting is very similar every year. And now i can solve almost all of this tasks except of one: There is always one Question about the "p vs. np" Problem.

An example of the lat year:

We have given the "Tile Cover" Problem witch says:
We have a "big" rectangle with a page length of 
n x m ∈ N
and we have k "small" rectangles ("tiles") r1, r2, ..., rk

The Question is if all the "small" rectangles fit in the "big" one without leaving any space on it.

And now ther are some tasks for this Problem and i already despair on the first one witch says:

"Justify informal why the 'Tile Cover' problem is in NP"

How to solve this Problem, or a similar one (bacause i dont think it will be the same in this year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a well-known characterization of the complexity class `NP` says that `NP` is comprised of precisely those problems for which, given a problem instance `I` and a certificate `C(I)`, we can verify in polynomial time that the instance `I` has a solution (using the certificate, of which one can think of as a hint to the algorithm). More concretely, one can think of the certificate as a solution to the problem instance (although it's more general than that). (The proof of the theorem formalizing this claim can be found in the superb book by Sanjeev Arora and Boaz Barak.)

Thus to show that a problem is in `NP` it suffices to prove that, given a solution to a problem instance, we can verify in time polynomial in the size of the solution and the size of the problem that the solution is indeed valid.

For your specific case, it suffices to show that if we are given a rectangle `R` and a set of "small" rectangles `S`, and a solution to the problem---a tiling of `R` with tiles from `S`---, then there is an algorithm that verifies that the tiling is good (or valid or whatever you call it) in polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it got a little more clear. Although I do not think that i will solve such a question in my exam ;). But at least now i understand the approach ...

Comment: Nice answer (with a nice book-recommendation)!

Answer (score -2):

I guess we are studying for the same exam. In my opinion, TILE COVER is in NP, because you have k small tiles => the problem can be solved in expotential time (k!).